# average with multiple conditions on excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, average, formulas

I generally ask Python or VBA questions, but this has been annoying me for the past 4.5 hours and i need it to finish a macros and i'm just getting div/0 error.

In excel i have five columns: 
1. Date when the item entered the queue (A)
2. time when the item entered the queue (B)
3. Date when the item left the queue (C)
4. time when the item left the queue (D)
5. time the item was in the queue (E)

I need the average of time of the items that entered and left the queue between 16:00 yesterday and 16:00 today. Also for it to ignore numbers < than 1 (because if an item has been there for over 24 hours the default value is negative).

I tried tried this and no results :(

=AVERAGEIFS(E1:E4,A1:A4,"=today()-1",B1:B4,">16:00",C1:C4,"=today()",D1:D4,"<16:00")

Any ideas would be appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: sorry my bad, already edited

Comment: It would also be useful if you added the contents of A1:E4 so we could test...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is saying this:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(E1:E4,A1:A4,"=today()-1",B1:B4,">16:00",C1:C4,"=today()",D1:D4,"<16:00")
```

> Take the average of E1:E4 if...
>
> 1. A1:A4 are equivalent to the string "=today()-1"
> 2. B1:B4 are equivalent to the string ">16:00"
> 3. C1:C4 are equivalent to the string "=today()"
> 4. D1:D4 are equivalent to the string ">16:00"

What you *want* it to say is:

> Take the average of E1:E4 if...
>
> 1. A1:A4 are equivalent to the result of the formula `=today()-1`
> 2. B1:B4 are less than 16 hours
> 3. C1:C4 are equivalent to the result of the formula `=today()`
> 4. D1:D4 are less than 16 hours

Let's tackle 2 and 4 first.

In Excel, 1 day (24 hours) = 1. Times are stored as decimal values as a percentage of a day:

1 day = 1
1 day = 24 hours
1 hour = 1 / 24
16 hours = 16/24 = 2/3

So instead of `B1:B4,">16:00"` you should rewrite the formula as:

```
B1:B4,">"&2/3
```

The `&` concatenates the greater than sign, and 2/3 will give the decimal value equivalent to 16:00. In the end you will get a string equal to ">.6666666666"

(You can also just use `B1:B4,">.6666666666666"` if you'd like)

For items 1 and 3, you don't need to use quotes at all. So instead of `A1:A4,"=today()-1"` you can just use the following:

```
A1:A4,today()-1
C1:C4,today()
```

Putting this all together, the following formula should work:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(E1:E4,A1:A4,today()-1,B1:B4,">"&2/3,C1:C4,today(),D1:D4,"<"&2/3)
```

Comment: @ jmac - actually ">16:00" as a criterion will work exactly as intended, it will do the same as ">"&2/3

Comment: @barryhoudini nice to see you on here too -- you would know better than I (for certain). Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: that works excellent! thanks! i just have a question, in column F i have 4 categories (Internal, External, Transfer and Risky) and i try to add the first 3 as criteria, for example: F1:F4, "Internal" , i just get DIV/0, any ideas why?

Comment: It is clearly finding no values with "Internal" so the denominator is zero. Are you sure you have entries that fill all conditions? If not, `=AVERAGEIFS()` will return a `#DIV/0` error. You can workaround this by wrapping the whole `=AVERAGEIFS()` statement in an `=IFERROR()` statement (that will just change what it displays -- not the underlying issue).

Comment: is there by any chance a way to ignore if "Internal" is or isn't in that range? because it will not always be there, i'm sorry for all the questions, this is a little out of my scope, generally i use python more than excel :-/

Comment: Yes, there are lots of ways, but I suggest reading [the documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/averageifs-function-HA010047493.aspx) first because it will answer 99% of questions as far as the basic uses of the function. In general, posting the data, as well as expected results makes it far easier to troubleshoot. Right now everyone can only guess what you want to do with the additional column, so if the documentation doesn't answer, please ask a separate question with some sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for "items that entered and left the queue between 16:00 yesterday and 16:00 today" isn't it possible that some of those entered the queue **today** (or left the queue yesterday)? If so you would need to check for items that entered today as well, surely? To do that is difficult with `AVERAGEIFS` function - it might be easier to use an "array formula" like this:

`=AVERAGE(IF(A1:A4+B1:B4>=TODAY()-1/3,IF(C1:C4+D1:D4<TODAY()+2/3,E1:E4)))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

I'm assuming that the formula doesn't have to explicitly deal with your negative values because those will only occur for items which have been there for more than 24 hours and the IF functions will exclude those anyway...

If you want to do the same with AVERAGEIFS you'd need to create two additional columns with the entry/exit dates/times added, e.g. if column G is the sum of columns A and B and column H is the sum of columns C and D you could use this version

`=AVERAGEIFS(E1:E4,G1:G4,">="&TODAY()-1/3,H1:H4,"<"&TODAY()+2/3)`

Note that I used >= and < deliberately to avoid double-counting/non-counting across several days